# Should I trust logistic regression in ABC model selection with more statistics than retained simulations?

Tags: logistic, nnet, approximate-bayesian-computation

I am using multinomial logistic regression to aid model selection in approximate Bayesian computation. However, I just realize at the preferred tolerance, the number of retained simulations is actually lower than the number of summary statistics, yet R does not complain. As I understand, the function I'm using (postpr in the "abc" package) eventually calls nnet to perform logistic regression. I tend to get extreme posterior probabilities (0 or 1), but higher tolerance levels produce poorer results in cross validation.

I wonder how nnet treats such cases? Can I still trust the result?